# ListView with Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, adapter, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to make a listview which consists of a horizontal scrollview as each one of the rows. I want the elements to be lined up vertically so the view would become scrollable if there are more then a certain amount of items.

However it comes out looking like this.

[image]

I am inflating the following xml

**single_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.example.jj.library.ChipView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/text_chip_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my adapter to add the views to the view

**Adapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.example.jj.library.Chip;
import com.example.jj.library.ChipView;
import com.example.jj.library.ChipViewAdapter;
import com.example.jj.library.OnChipClickListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jj on 12/21/2015.
 */
public class LiveFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LiveFeedDataProvider> implements OnChipClickListener {


    private static final String TAG = "LIVEFEED ADAPTER";
    Context CTX;
    private ChipView mTextChipLayout;
    public List<LiveFeedDataProvider> liveFeed_list = new ArrayList<LiveFeedDataProvider>();

    public LiveFeedAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        CTX = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(LiveFeedDataProvider object){
        liveFeed_list.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return liveFeed_list.size();
    }


    @Override
    public LiveFeedDataProvider getItem(int position) {

        return liveFeed_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) CTX.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_livefeed_row,parent,false);
        }
        ChipViewAdapter adapterLayout = new MainChipViewAdapter(getContext());
        mTextChipLayout = (ChipView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_chip_layout);
        mTextChipLayout.setAdapter(adapterLayout);
        mTextChipLayout.setChipLayoutRes(R.layout.chip_close);
        mTextChipLayout.setChipBackgroundColor(CTX.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
        mTextChipLayout.setChipBackgroundColorSelected(CTX.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        mTextChipLayout.setOnChipClickListener(this);
        LiveFeedDataProvider provider = liveFeed_list.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "LENGTH = " + provider.interests.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < provider.interests.length; i++) {
            String interest = provider.interests[i];
            mTextChipLayout.add(new Tag(interest));
        }
            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChipClick(Chip chip) {

    }

}
```

Comment: your linearlayout just above chipview has layout vertical.

Comment: @RusheelJain I changed to horizontal and still the same answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved your problem in a bit different way: I replaced `HorizontalScrollView` and `ListView` by a `RecyclerView` with each row as a `RecyclerView` which, as I believe, is a preferred layout here.

Here's a result:

[image]

(don't pay to much attention to an ugly design :-) )

`MainActivity` layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

`MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView chipRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        chipRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ArrayList<String[]> chipsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        chipsArray.add(new String[] {"Fitness", "Gaming", "Education","Animals", "Cars"});
        .....
        chipsArray.add(new String[] {"Education","Animals", "Cars"});

        chipRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ListChipsAdapter(chipsArray));
    }
}
```

`ListChipsAdapter` - adapter for the `MainActivity`'s recycler view. It manages list of rows with chips.

```
public class ListChipsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private ArrayList<String[]> chipsArray;

    public ListChipsAdapter(ArrayList<String[]> chipsArray) {
        this.chipsArray = chipsArray;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ChipsViewHolder(new RowChipsView(parent.getContext()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((RowChipsView)holder.itemView).setAdapter(new ChipsAdapter(chipsArray.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chipsArray.size();
    }

    private class ChipsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ChipsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

`RowChipsView` - is a class which represents the particular single row:

```
public class RowChipsView extends FrameLayout {

    public RowChipsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeView(context);
    }

    private void initializeView(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_row, this);
        ((RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHorizontal)).setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }

    public void setAdapter(ChipsAdapter adapter) {
        ((RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHorizontal)).setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

It's Layout is consist of only one `RecyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"/>
```

Now, `ChipsAdapter` - the adapter which is used by each single row:

```
public class ChipsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private String[] chipsArray;

    public ChipsAdapter(String[] chipsArray) {
        this.chipsArray = chipsArray;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ChipViewHolder(new ChipView(parent.getContext()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((ChipView)holder.itemView).displayItem(chipsArray[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chipsArray.length;
    }

    private class ChipViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ChipViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the last piece is a `ChipView`:

```
public class ChipView extends FrameLayout {

    public ChipView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeView(context);
    }

    private void initializeView(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.chip_view, this);
    }

    public void displayItem(String text) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.chipTextView)).setText(text);
    }
}
```

and it's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chipTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I've uploaded the project to my dropbox, so [feel free to check it out!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5hmfc6n3tx6gznn/HorizontalVerticals.zip?dl=0)

I hope, it helps.

Comment: Note that if you choose to put your RecyclerAdapter's ViewHolder class in the same file as your RecyclerAdapter, you should declare it as static. Otherwise you'll run in to memory problems sooner or later.

Comment: it helped me Thanks