# Android: How to implement a image gallery with RecyclerView

Tags: android, arraylist, null, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

I want to create a image gallery with a `TextView` as header and `ImageViews` in a `HorizontalScrollView` like it is displayed in this [figure](http://image.wjxfpf.com/upload/c/5e/c5e096e228d1b38ff1016bd5ddf13681.gif).

I use a `RecyclerView`to reduce the ressources for my app and implement the images with many `ArrayList` like:

```js
        itemFotoIDs.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                R.drawable.cable_crunches_1
                ,R.drawable.dips_1
                ,R.drawable.kabelrudern_breit_1
                ,R.drawable.kabelrudern_eng_1
                ,R.drawable.klimmzug_1
                ,R.drawable.kh_schulterdruecken_1
                ,R.drawable.kh_curls_1
                ,R.drawable.lh_bankdruecken_1
                ,R.drawable.lh_bankdruecken_eng_1
                ,R.drawable.lh_kniebeuge_1
                ,R.drawable.lh_kreuzheben_1
                ,R.drawable.lh_schraegbankdruecken_1
                ,R.drawable.latzug_obergriff_1
                ,R.drawable.seitheben_1
                ,R.drawable.szhantel_curls_1
        ));
```

**Now my question:** What is the best solution to create a empty entry in a line of this `ArrayList`, if e.g. i've got five `ArrayList` with 15 entries and two only have 14 or 13 entries. But I want the empty entry at the exact row and not at the end. 
I tried to implement a `null` instead of the `R.drawable.` but this leads to a crash of the app.

Comment: Do want to show a default image when a drawable is empty?

Comment: That would be a possibility. But no, I don't want to show a default image, because the HorizontalScrollView should stop after the last image of each raw.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like refer my own answer in a slightly similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34462696/1658267  (NB! going forward, I'd use class/methods naming from there)

The only difference would be to replace `TextViews` with `ImageView`s. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chipImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Regarding the empty slots - there're multiple options:

- You can pass nulls, and then in something which was called `ChipView`(in your case - view with image), in `displayItem()` method check if parameter is null - then just set proper width to the `View`
- You can create separate `viewType` for horizontal `RecyclerView` and create an empty view for it(as a placeholder). Then you need slightly to update `ChipsAdapter`:

  ```
  static int IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE = 1;
  static int EMPTY_SLOP_TYPE = 2;

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      if (viewType = IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE) {
          return new ChipViewHolder(new ChipView(parent.getContext()));
      } else {
          return new ChipViewHolder(new EmptyView(parent.getContext()));
      }
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      return chipsArray[position] == null? EMPTY_SLOP_TYPE : IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      if (holder.itemView instanceof ChipView) {
          ((ChipView) holder.itemView).displayItem(chipsArray[position]);
      }
  }
  ```

  And create an `EmptyView`, with pre-defined not-0 width.

Personally I prefer the second option (decoupling, easier to maintain onClick - without extra logic there, etc.)

I hope, it helps.