# How to implement Horizontal Scroll View inside a simple ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to implement Horizontal Scroll View inside a simple List View. The elements inside the horizontal scroll view are texts over images.

I know I need to create the adapter and the getter & setter class as well for horizontal Scrolling elements.

Also, the URLs of the images are stored in a string array. But I am not sure how to implement that.

Can any one suggest a good example for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458123/listview-with-horizontal-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Before requesting for answer make sure you try to implement/google it.

I would suggest you to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.

For your requirement you will need two Adapters one for your parent `RecyclerView` and another for your item if `RecyclerView`.

Refer the [link](https://irpdevelop.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/horizontal-recyclerview-inside-a-vertical-recyclerview/). It'll help you to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager and orientation to HORIZONTAL