# Android listview with Color Border in vertical

Tags: android-layout, android-listview

I have been struggling for a while to draw vertical border.I want to use a ListView to make a report wheres the results is divided into squares and mixed up.Tried with multiple codes but could not, If any one can suggest the mistakes in my codings would be great.

Horizontal is working fine whereas vertical could not it.

Even with vertical in color do fine.

**Current Listview Appears as follows :** 
[image]

**Expected Listview format as follows:** Vertical and Horizontal Border or Grid needed in between the contents.
[image]

**Layout:**
**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFC7C7C7"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:divider="@drawable/mydivider"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:dividerPadding="22dp"
    android:weightSum="9">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FFC7C7C7"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductcompany"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.63"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="no"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductname"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.59"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="number"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="9sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice1"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="sun"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="mon"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="tuesday"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice4"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="wednesday"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice5"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="thursday"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice6"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="saturday"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice7"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="closed"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice8"
            android:layout_width="21dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="calling"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.60" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice9"
            android:layout_width="21dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="week"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_weight="6.22" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lvcontainer"
        android:layout_weight="8.72"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/separator_line"
        android:dividerHeight="4.0sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:dividerPadding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"


        ></ListView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtresulttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFF55F54"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"></TextView>




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvbottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnupload"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1083f5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="UPLOAD"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**

**Mycontroller:**

```js
myList = controller.getAllProducts();
        if (myList.size() != 0) {
            ListView lv = getListView();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(import2.this, myList,
                    R.layout.display2, new String[]{ "id","number", "outletname","sunday", "tuesday" , "wednesday" ,"thursday", "saturday" , "monday","calling","closed"}, new int[]{
                    R.id.txtproductcompany,R.id.txtproductname,R.id.txtproductprice,R.id.txtproductprice1,R.id.txtproductprice2,R.id.txtproductprice3,R.id.txtproductprice4,R.id.txtproductprice5,R.id.txtproductprice6,R.id.txtproductprice7,R.id.txtproductprice8});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            lbl.setText("");

        }
```

**code resutls.**
[image]

**Bar in the bottom,**

same like this .
[image]

Comment: Thanks for an interesting puzzle :) I found out why the header row got so high - take a look into he chat if you like

Comment: yes. it was very intresting where no one able to crack the solution except you and even i googled several but could not. Tried with gridview too but could not. Issue where height of the three layout which is corrected and got the results as desired with help of your codings.And i am sure this codings will help many others too..

Comment: @0X0nosugar how to add bar in the bottom to see the rightside contents? bar sample attached in the quesiton

Comment: not sure because of the ListView but I'd try to put everything inside a [horizontal ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView)

Comment: @0X0nosugar thank you.can you share codings if you have

Comment: Check this out: [ListView with Horizontal ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458123/listview-with-horizontal-scrollview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to show a table made of `ListView` rows, you have to make sure that columns will require the same space in each row.

Or you take an alternative approach and use [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout). It will be the better choice if you have a fixed number of rows.

But let's assume you have a varying number of rows. Then your layout for the rows will have to consist of rather rigid cells, so `android:width="wrap_content"` is not an option for most of the `View`s.

One way to cope with this is using a set of dimension values for the columns:

*dimens.xml*

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="column_id_width">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="column_number_width">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="column_outletname_width">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="column_weekday_width">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="column_closed_width">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="column_calling_width">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="column_week_width">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="column_wednesday_width">76dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

... as well as a style for the individual `TextView`s

```
<style name="ListItemStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/list_item_background</item>
</style>
```

with a shape drawable as *list_item_background*:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

The list header:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#aaaaaa"
    android:foreground="@drawable/list_header_foreground"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductcompany"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_id_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="id3"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductname"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_number_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="number"/>


    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="outletname"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sunday"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="monday"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tuesday"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice4"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_wednesday_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="wednesday"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice5"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="thursday"/>

    <!-- friday is missing on purpose? -->

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice6"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="saturday"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice7"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_closed_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="closed"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice8"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_calling_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="calling"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice9"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_week_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WEEK1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and, last not least, the list row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductcompany"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_id_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="13" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductname"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_number_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="9003562"/>


    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="1rmarket"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Sunday"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Monday"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Tuesday"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice4"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_wednesday_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Wednesday"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice5"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Thursday"/>

    <!-- friday is missing on purpose? -->

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice6"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_weekday_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="No"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice7"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_closed_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Yes"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice8"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_calling_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="0001\nDaily"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice9"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_week_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="WEEK1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: you can use an attribute `android:foreground` with the `LinearLayout` in the list header if you want that green frame overlaying the child `View`s. Another shape drawable similar to *list_item_background* will do the trick.

Please note also that since I don't know your exact requirements, I left some of the attributes related to dividers alone. You may want to get rid of them if the approach based on shape drawables solves your issue.

The picture shows the Android Studio preview of the list header above a `ListView` placeholder

[image: sketch of list header above ListView in design perspective]

I changed the Activity layout to use less layout weights, and everything is set to `android:visibility="visible"` to make sure it all fits on the screen:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#FFC7C7C7"
    android:divider="@drawable/mydivider"
    android:dividerPadding="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainer"
        layout="@layout/list_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFC7C7C7" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@drawable/separator_line"
        android:dividerHeight="4.0sp"
        android:dividerPadding="10dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtresulttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text=""
        tools:text="result"
        android:textColor="#FFF55F54"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvbottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnupload"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1083f5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="UPLOAD"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: my listview works fine but i would like to keep vertical and horizontal grid in between the data as mentioned in my question . Your answer shows only with horizontal. Please suggest

Comment: @Leace - my answer shows how to get a grid structure using shape drawables. The effect is similar to a HTML border

Comment: in this case i should have two layout file like one for list header and another one for list row ? or in single layout should i compine?

Comment: @Leace - if you use a single layout file you may have to apply small changes at runtime, for example the header field "id3" has a white background and the others are grey whereas the list row items all have the same background. I started with the header layout ad then I copied it to another layout file and changed it a bit to get the row layout. The important thing is to keep the column width values constant for both header and row layouts

Comment: list_header_foreground this info is missing ? and above listheader results attached above. whats is missing

Comment: @Leace - simply copy the shape drawable from list_item_background.xml and use another color in the *solid* tag

Comment: @Leace - sorry, I did not understand "above listheader results attached above"

Comment: i did the same as you mentioned in single layout. results is attached in my question in bottom " Code results"

Comment: @Leace - this looks like what I get in the preview for just the list header. My picture shows what it looks like when I use my list header in the activity layout (maybe I should share this as well, will edit my answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203624/discussion-between-leace-and-0x0nosugar).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user 0X0nosugar created three layout. 1.main layout 2. listheader 3.listrow and applied rest matrix as suggested. now working fine

Answer (score -2):

Use Views as borders in your adapter item layout. Use a recycler view instead.

Comment: do you have any sample codings since i tried with many codings but failed to respond back as desired.